# What is the purpose of these tags in a Wikipedia Table's Row?

Tags: wikipedia

I'm struggling to understand what keywords to google search to find information about a specific Wikipedia table:

This page contains three tables.
https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:cuisine#Food

This is the top one:
https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/w/index.php?title=Template:Map_Features:Cuisine_(ethnicity)&action=edit

Typical row:

```
[[{{{american:value|{{LL|1=Tag:cuisine=american}}}}} | american]]
| {{{american:desc| Food originating from the United States. Use a more specific value if possible. }}}
| {{{american:wikipedia| {{wikipedia|en|American cuisine|text=no}} }}}
| {{{american:photo|[[File:Motherhood and apple pie.jpg|100px|center]]}}}
```

Please point me to the relevant pages to understand:

- What 'LL' represents.
- What '1=' is used for.
- What is the purpose of the namespace labels, in this example"american:"

Are they Openstreetmap wiki specific?
Do they relate only to wiki tables?

Comment: This should get you started: [Wikipedia Help: Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Link)

Answer (score 1):

`LL` is the name of a template, in this case referring to https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Template:LL, which links to a given page in the correct language. This specific template is not a built-in MediaWiki feature, but many other MediaWiki wikis have templates with similar names and features.

`1=` is generic syntax that can be used on any MediaWiki wiki to explicitly specify that a parameter is numeric even if it contains an equals sign. `{{LL|Tag:cuisine=american}}` would pass `american` as a parameter named `Tag:cuisine` to the LL template, whereas `{{LL|1=Tag:cuisine=american}}` passes `Tag:cuisine=american` as the `1` parameter (equivalent to the first unnamed parameter) to the template. In sufficiently recent MediaWiki versions `{{LL|Tag:cuisine{{=}}american}}` also works.

`{{{american:value|...}}}` is a parameter name, defaulting to the above expression (`{{LL|1=Tag:cuisine=american}}`) if no `american:value` parameter is given, as is the case on https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:cuisine#Food. Some other page could do `{{Map Features:Cuisine (ethnicity)|american:value=...}}` and override the given parameter, although it appears no pages on the wiki do. The use of a colon for namespacing is a wiki convention and ignored by the software itself, which treats `american:value` as an opaque string.